# how to set an input lang style code?

Tags: html

good day, i'm trying to set a lang code for an input html
is there any way to add this like:

```
<input type="text" value="إكتب هنا" **Style="font-lang:en;"**>
```

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the lang property like so:

```
<input type="text" value="إكتب هنا" lang="en">
```

You have all the language codes in the link below and also the reference from where you can learn more about the lang property.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp

Comment: doesn't work too, it writes the numbers in arabic because i set the table direction "rtl" and i want to write english numbers

Comment: note: when i set the table direction "lrt" it writes in english successfully, but the form is being inverted

Comment: is it hard to find an answer here ?

Comment: change the lang en to ar.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the HTML global `lang` attribute available. See [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_lang.asp).

Comment: my sir, it doesn't work, i need to add a code in style like this  text-lang:en;

Comment: this code: <input type="text" value="إكتب هنا" onfocus="(this.value == \'إكتب هنا\') && (this.value = \'\')"onblur="(this.value == \'\') && (this.value = \'إكتب هنا\')" name="ct_captcha" size="3" style="color: #00FFFF; text-align: left; vertical-align: middle; border:1px solid #FFff00; height:82px; background color:#001003; background:#001003; font-family:Arial; font-size:53px; font-weight:bold; padding:1px" maxlength="6" />

i hope to find for example: font-lang:en-us;